# Problems with carriage returns when running make docs on Restructured Text files, Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, makefile, restructuredtext, carriage-return

I have two dev machines, one Debian, the other Windows 10.

I'm having trouble with the Debian laptop (hardware) so I'm temporarily trying to move my work to Windows. I'm far more comfortable with Debian.

I'm running `make docs` on ReStructured Text files in my client's repo. **I should say here that I'm a newb to Python repos and to RST**.

On Debian: no issues. `make docs` runs to completion.

On Windows 10: carriage return validation errors.

**I use Git Bash for CLI work in Windows.**

I've tried the three different options of `core.autocrlf` in `.gitattributes` to no avail. I've checked out a branch with each option enabled: same error each time.

I want to get to a root cause here. Yes, I could run dos2unix but it doesn't address the root cause.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?  Is the problem that the file is supposed to contain CRLF line endings but has LF line endings?  Or is it supposed to contain LF line endings but has CRLF line endings?

Comment: >`docs\technical_reference\named_releases.rst:426: D004 Found literal carriage return
>========
>Total files scanned = 19
>Total files ignored = 0
>Total accumulated errors = 769
>Detailed error counts:
 >   - doc8.checks.CheckCarriageReturn = 769
>...

>ERROR: InvocationError for command 'C:\Users\testi\Repos\edx-developer-docs\.tox\docs\Scripts\doc8.EXE' --ignore-path docs/_build README.rst docs (exited with code 1)`

Comment: Sorry, trying to blockquote that and it's not working, ugh.

Comment: I found the place where I can tell doc8 to ignore the carriage returns: the tox.ini in the root directory. `make docs` is now happily running.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the information.  You can't put formatted content into comments.

Answer (score 0):

doc8 was out of maintenance for a long time, and most importantly not well tested on Windows. The bug you noticed was only fixed last September and not included in any stable releases yet,

https://github.com/PyCQA/doc8/pull/47

You might try to delete doc8 usage from the repo and replace with other linters like [rstcheck](https://pypi.org/project/rstcheck/).